# Spring LDAP and REST authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-ldap

I have used the Spring LDAP library to integrate a login function via a REST interface

After the user has called my login REST method I need to validate they have login when they call subsequent REST apis

I was thinking of using the session to store a boolean to say the user had passed login with a predefined time but I would rather avoid using sessions as in the future I plan to have a few more app servers.

I tried looking through the Spring LDAP docs but was unable to find anything which would help. Ideally I would like to generate some type of LDAP token which can be passed back to the client and which can be added as a attribute to other REST methods. The server can then validate the token with the LDAP server

Comment: Can't you use your application servers authentication and authorization mechanisms? So you don't have to implement everything, which has already been implemented,...

Comment: I am exposing a REST interface which has a login method for username / password. I am not sure how I can use the tomcat realm security for this